# Overloading placement new operator with data member initialization and difference with normal new operator

Tags: c++

I am writing an overloaded version of placement new and want to initialize an integer data member inside the function.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
struct A {
    int i;
    void* operator new(size_t, void *p, int x) { return p; }
};
int main() {
    A* pa = new(malloc(sizeof(A)), 10) A;
    pa->~A();
    delete pa;
}
```

I would like to know how to do it in the above code. 
Also,

```
class A {
public:
    static int* p;
    void* operator new(size_t sz, unsigned int val) {
        p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(val));
        *p = val;
    }
};
int* A::p;
int main() {
    A *p= new (10) A(); // calls overloaded new with initialization and not placement new
    cout << *(p->p) << endl; // Ans: 10
}
```

In the above code, the syntax looks similar to placement new however it calls the overloaded new version. So how the compiler differentiates between overloaded placement new and operator new? Is that based on the argument type (i.e) void*? what if have a data member which is void* and it should be initialized via a void* argument? How the compiler handles this?

Comment: Why are you explicitly calling the destructor? `delete pa;` will already do so.

Answer (score 4):

> So how the compiler differentiates between overloaded placement new and operator new?

It doesn't. A placement-new expression calls an overload of `operator new` with parameters that match the placement arguments (if such an overload exists). So the standard placement new

```
new (p) A;
```

calls the overload declared in `<new>`

```
void* operator new(size_t, void*);
```

while your expression, with different argument types, calls your overload, since the types match.

> Is that based on the argument type (i.e) `void*`?

Yes, that's exactly how it works.

> what if have a data member which is `void*` and it should be initialized via a `void*` argument?

Data members should be initialised by the constructor, not `operator new`. You should only override `operator new` if you want to control how the memory is allocated before initialising the object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Placement (as in "extra parameter", not "no actual allocation") `new` is for allocating memory. Initialization is what the constructor is for.

Although weird and unlikely, there's technically no reason that the C++ implementation cannot include code that wipes the memory area returned by your new implementation before it initializes the object in that area. It could wipe it to "all zero" or some debug bit pattern.